# Programmatic remove <td> from php generated HTML table

Tags: php, html, dom, html-table

I would like to remove extraneous table cells that are generated from an html table in php.
Please see end of table in this example:http://leobee.com/android/push/so/stdt3.php
**Note I have not updated the code to work in IE yet, please use a gecko browser.

I've found this example in jQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tr_deletecell. However I need to remove the extra cells after the colspan cells are generated in php.

Questions:

1. Is it possible for php to manipulate the DOM to remove table cells after the colspan cells have been processed? if possible can you stipulate the process of figuring this out or what methods or libraries I should look into.
2. Do you know of another example that is similar to my table that can programmatic create a schedule for a day broken down by hour, that can have an event expand over more than one hour?

Code:

```
<?php

// events array
$events = array(
    array('Atari', 'Hall D' , '10:00 PM'),
    array('Sonic the Hedgehog', 'Panel 4' , '11:00 AM'),
    array('Bleach', 'Video 3' , '4:00 PM'),
    array('Sailor Moon ', 'Panel 4' , '6:00 PM') 
);

$events_flat = array();

foreach($events as $event)
{
    $events_flat[$event[0]] = $event[1] . $event[2];
}

// location array
$locations = array(
    'Arena', 'Hall D', 'Video 1', 'Video 2', 'Video 3',
    'Video 4', 'Video 5', 'Video 6', 'HD Theater', 'Panel 1', 
    'Panel 2', 'Panel 3', 'Panel 4', 'WorkShop 1', 'WorkShop 2',
    'WorkShop 3', 'WorkShop 4', 'Autograph 1', 'Autograph 2'
);

// event start time array
$times = array(
    '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM','12:00 PM', '1:00 PM', '2:00 PM',
    '3:00 PM', '4:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '6:00 PM', '7:00 PM',
    '8:00 PM', '9:00 PM', '10:00 PM', '11:00 PM', '12:00 AM',
    '1:00 AM', '2:00 AM'
);

$html = '<table><tr><td bgcolor="green"><table name="schedule" id="schedule" border="1" bordercolor="black"><tr><td></td>';

foreach ($times as $time)
{
    $html .= '<td width="100" height="25" bgcolor="yellow">';
    $html .= htmlspecialchars($time);
    $html .= '</td>';
}

foreach ($locations as $location)
{
    $html .= '<tr><td width="100" height="25" bgcolor="pink">';
    $html .= htmlspecialchars($location);
    $html .= '</td>';

    foreach ($times as $time)
    {


       $event = array_search($location . $time, $events_flat);

        if ($event === FALSE)
        {
            $html .= '<td width="100" height="25" bgcolor="#70DBDB">';
            $html .= ' ';


        }
        else
        {
            //http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tr_deletecell
            //http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php
            //duration in hours
            // Todo detect ie and use colSpan
            $duration =3;
            $html .= '<td colspan="'.$duration.'" width="100" height="25" bgcolor="orange">';
            $html .= htmlspecialchars($event);
            //$event = array_pop($event-1);


        }

        $html .= '</td>';
      // $deletecell=document.getElementById("schedule").rows[this];
      //  $deletecell.deleteCell(-1);
    }

    $html .= ' </tr>';
}

$html .=  '</table></td></tr></table>';

echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this, from the user's point of view?  Are you just trying to hide certain records after the page is rendered?

Comment: Why not modify your PHP code to generate the correct output instead of trying to remove it afterwards?

Comment: You also need to understand the difference between serverside (php) and clientside (dom, javascript). If you don't want things to be sent to the browser, make sure they're not created on the server

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm  not trying to hide records. It is that the I trying to figure out how to compensate for the colsapn pushing extra cell out of range of the table's column headers.

Comment: @freefaller I think you are pointing out that I am  using php to generate a table for display of information, when this is not the true use of php. I understand However, I'm just trying to figure out the logistics of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider fixing your output instead of knowingly producing a wrong one and then trying to correct it afterwards.

Instead of using `foreach`, you could just use a regular `for` loop with an incremented variable `i` used to grab each `$time` at index `i` of the arrays. Then you could just increment `i` by the extra duration if you find an event, thereby making less `<td>` cells.

```
else
{
    $duration = 3;
    $html .= '<td colspan="'.$duration.'" width="100" height="25" bgcolor="orange">';
    $html .= htmlspecialchars($event);
    $i += $duraton - 1 // subtract 1 since $i will be incremented after this iteration
}
```

Basically, you are increasing the time by 3 time slots instead of the usual 1 when finding an event, since each event takes up 3 slots. Note that this can be extended to work for events of any duration.

As a side note, I don't know php so my syntax might be wrong. If so, please correct me. This should be enough to give the general idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try a different approach to achieve the chart in the link in my question using 'horizontal stacked bar chart'.